# remote access to NAS and database

Tags: remote-access, nas, synology

I have a postgreSql database running on NAS synology ds216j.

From my host I can access the NAS control panel (http://x.x.x.x:5000/)and I can see the database files but I cannot run them straight from there. (LibreOfficeBase)
If, instead, I access through the dav://x.x.x.x:5005 connection created on my pc I can.

Why?

I would like to run this database from remote, how can I allow another host (outside my LAN) to run the db?
I can give access to the NAS control panel creating another user and quickconnect, but I cannot run the DB